# Weakening Goldbach hypothesis by allowing finitely many composites and 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, open-problem, goldbachs-conjecture

Is it an open question whether there is a finite set $N$ of positive integers such that for every positive even integer $n$ there are $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb P\cup N$ such that $n=n_1+n_2$? ($\mathbb P$ denotes the set of prime numbers)

Comment: I honestly don't know, but my instinct tells me that yes, this is an open question, since it is way too close to the actual Goldbach conjecture.